# Process user's input which is a sequence of requests

Tags: c++

I have a homework, my program has to receive a sequence of requests, then it will show data based on what users enter. Here is some example of user's inputs:

1. "CL"  : return number of lines in the dataset
2. "CL city_name" : return number of lines in the city given, if the city doesn't exist, return -1
3. "LSC city_name" : List stations (station_id) of a city (given city_name)

.........

(city_name is replacible)

Please don't care about dataset, it's not important. What I wanna ask here is how to process user's input to call the right function. For example, if user enters "CL", the function funCL() will be called, "CL Tokyo", the function funCL("Tokyo") will be called. That's all !
Sorry for my grammar. I don't mean to make any bad attitude. Thank you for paying attention !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For the best results, please attempt to solve the problem first and then ask questions about your attempted solution if necessary. You may create a solution that works or only needs a small fix. If not, at least potential answerers have a an example they can work from to compose an answer that fills in any misunderstandings you may have. Without an example, we do not know where to start on helping you.

Comment: I will try not to make a mistake like that again. Thanks for your comment !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
if(argc<=1){
    printf("show help(how to use the program)");
}
if(argc==2 && strcmp("CL",argv[1]) == 0) {
    printf("number of lines in the DataSet is ...");
}
if(argc==3 && strcmp("CL",argv[1]) == 0) {
    calculate_number_of_line_city(argv[2]);
}
if(argc==3 && strcmp("LSC",argv[1]) == 0) {
    list_stations(argv[2]);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! But what the input parses in form of char[], and the program just receive a ref to that char[]. So I think argc will not work

Comment: you will pass arguments to your prog using console ?
if yes argc will contain the number of arguments, and argv[i] will not be empty if argc is > "number of arg you put (i arguments) ". and argv[0] will generally contain the path to your program

Comment: I got it. Thanks for your help !